# Validar Integridad Referencial laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

En laravel 5.1 existe alguna forma de validar la integridad referencial de los datos?

Me explico. Tengo 2 tablas relacionadas por un FK Donde Pais puede tener varios Departamentos (o Estados), como puedo validar cuando un usuario quiera eliminar un País que ya tiene Departamentos relacionados, mostrarle al usuario un mensaje que le indique porque no se puede, en vez de que el sistema envie el DELETE a la base de datos y ésta me genere el error de Foreign Key

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sisoft`.`departamento`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Pais_idPais_departamento` FOREIGN KEY (`Pais_idPais`) REFERENCES `pais` (`idPais`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) (SQL: delete from `pais` where `idPais` = 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el método `destroy` de tu controlador PaisController puedes hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
public function destroy(Pais $pais)
{
    if(count($pais->departamentos)){
        return // La vista que quieras en caso de que no se pueda borrar
    }
    Pais::destroy($pais->id);
    return // La vista que quieras tras borrar el país
}
```

Simplemente compruebas que el país que se va a eliminar no tenga departamentos asociados (mediante una relación establecida en tus modelos con el método `departamentos()` ), y si los tiene mandas al usuario a dónde quieras diciéndole que no se puede borrar.